# Querying for a specific value in a String stored in a database field

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
{"create_channel":"1","update_comm":"1","channels":"*"}
```

This is the database field which I want to query.

What would my query look like if I wanted to select all the records that have a `"create_channel": "1"` and a `"update_comm": "1"`

**Additional question:**

View the field below:

```
{"create_channel":"0","update_comm":"0","channels":[{"ch_id":"33","news":"1","parties":"1","questions ":"1","cam":"1","edit":"1","view_subs":"1","invite_subs":"1"},{"ch_id":"18","news":"1","parties":"1","questions ":"1","cam":"1","edit":"1","view_subs":"1","invite_subs":"1"}]}
```

How would I go about finding out all those that are subadmins in the `News`, `parties`, `questions` and `Cams` sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `->>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to return a member as a string:

```
select  * 
from    YourTable 
where   YourColumn->>'create_channel' = '1' and
        YourColumn->>'update_comm' = '1'
```

To find a user who has news, parties, questions and cam in channel 33, you can use [the `@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to check if the channels array contains those properties:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   YourColumn->'channels' @> '[{
            "ch_id":"33",
            "news":"1",
            "parties":"1",
            "questions ":"1",
            "cam":"1"
        }]';
```